# $e^z=-3i$ find $z\in \mathbb C$ check my answer

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, exponentiation

I am unsure of my solution to this question, since the definition of the complex logarithm is somewhat complex.

Since $-3i = 3e^{i\frac{3}{2}\pi}$ we get that $e^z=3e^{i\frac{3}{2}\pi}$

So if we use logarithm function like we did in $\mathbb R$ we would get

$z=\ln(3e^{i\frac{3}{2}\pi})=\ln3+\ln(e^{i\frac{3}{2}\pi})=\ln3+i\frac{3}{2}\pi$

Is this the correct answer? Are there more correct answers?

Comment: Yes, there are, for example $\ln 3 - i \frac{1}{2}\pi$

Comment: how would I reach these new solutions?

Comment: There's a theorem saying that for any $w \in \mathbb{C}, w \neq 0$, the equation $e^z = w$ has a solution and all the solutions of this equation differ by $2k\pi i$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That's true, but I meant more solutions in the interval $(0,2\pi]$

Comment: No, if you state the condition $\Im w \in [0, 2\pi)$, then you obtain a unique solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea: putting $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$

$$-3i=e^{z}=e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y$$

Now compare real and imaginary parts and stuff.